# How to force DIV inside an LI (with overflow hidden styling) still show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got 3 LI with class=box and they are styled with overflow hidden.  I need to create a DIV with class=badge inside one box (in this case the 3rd/blue box).

My objective is: 
1. that this badge DIV (set as position absolute) follows or can use as reference the relative position of that particular box.
2. that this yellow badge DIV can be displayed outside of the blue box.

I have been trying a lot of things to make this mission impossible code, but I was wondering if anybody here has already done this before.

Preferred solution: Javascript or jQuery and workable in IE8 if possible if not at least IE9.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <li class="box" style="background-color: red;">
        red
    </li>
    <li class="box" style="background-color: green;">
        green
    </li>
    <li class="box" style="background-color: blue;">
        <div style="background-color: #ff0;" class="badge">badge</div>
        blue
    </li>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    border:1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 20px auto 0px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.badge {
    position: absolute;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    bottom: -55px;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px; 5px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

NOTE: overflow hidden code is commented, for you to see the output I need to have.

I have a jsfiddle here for quick reference:
 http://jsfiddle.net/philcyb/1m73qewm/

Comment: I don't follow you, do you want the container to size appropriately to fit the yellow container in?

Comment: @mattytommo thanks for you reply. my objective is this: if the overflow:hidden style of .box is enabled, I still want the .badge Div showing the whole DIV. not just the part of it. meaning, to force it to be visible, even if it is inside the LI with overflow:hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/1m73qewm/6/):

```
var $badge = $('div.badge'),
    xOffset = $badge.offset();
$badge.appendTo('body').css({
    top: xOffset.top,
    left: xOffset.left
});
```

You probably need to add scrollTop() and the like too.

Comment: Yup, I came up with something similar: http://jsfiddle.net/1m73qewm/7/ - the only way I can think of is moving the element outside of the container.

Comment: @Ferret Brilliant idea. Good stuff. Thank you. :) 

I just have one small small problem that needs to be resolved. When i resize the browser horizontally (noticed when I hit inspect elements), the position-left of the ".badge" follows that of the farthest left of the browser. and not of the ".container". It would work for websites with left aligned containers but not for centered ones.

Is there such code that the offset references on the ".container" then follows it when the browser is horizontally resized? 

Vertical scrolling is fine though.

TY also - pawel

Comment: Then try to give .container a "position:relative" and change the code to: http://jsfiddle.net/1m73qewm/10/

Answer (score 1):

So the simplest solution that is supported by what you require would be to add another parent that does your clipping for you.

Simple have the structure such as `.box > .box-inner > text + badge`

An example of how that would look for your blue box would be.

```
<li class="box" style="background-color: blue;">
    <div class="box-inner">
        Blue
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #ff0;" class="badge">badge</div>
</li>
```

The CSS for the inner box would be

```
.box-inner {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

I have updated your fiddle with what that would look like.

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/1m73qewm/12/

Comment: ~ Thanks for sharing your code.  This one also works for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<li class="box" style="background-color: blue;">
    <div style="background-color: #ff0;" class="box">badge</div>
    blue
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px; 5px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I presume this is what you mean't ! Just see the changes in the above code.

Comment: ~ No. The badge Div is meant to be a different box. My idea is like this: the 3 boxes are 3 APPS icons on say iphone screen; and the badge box is meant to be like the red notification badge on top of one of these boxes or all. Though this codes are meant for desktop website. :)